# java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:xxxx while invoking Firefox browser in Headless mode

Tags: java, maven, selenium, geckodriver, firefox-headless

I am getting a "java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost"
error whenever I try to initialize the FirefoxDriver. Any Help?

Code and Stack Trace Below:

Java Code

```
firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
firefoxBinary.addCommandLineOptions("--headless");

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", (String) pluginConfig.get("geckodriver"));
firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();

firefoxOptions.setBinary(firefoxBinary);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

This line throws the error

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:5054 Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z' System info: host: 'xxxxx-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-127-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_171' Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'xxxxxx-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-127-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at
```

Comment: OS: Ubuntu(Linux) 16.04 
Selenium Version: '3.12.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it.The problem was that, I was using a corrupted copy of geckodriver and it gave the following error above the stacktrace.

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ fetcher-firefox ---
path/to/geckodriver: 2: path/to/geckodriver: Syntax error: newline unexpected
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:15615
```

Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'xxxxx-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-127-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_171'

Details of the issue can be found here:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6013#issuecomment-396665924

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the contents of **pluginConfig** file. In general to invoke **Firefox Browser** in **Headless Mode** programatically through *Selenium 3.12.0*, *GeckoDriver v 0.20.1*, *Firefox Quantum v60.0.2* and *Java* you need to pass the `argument` **--headless** through an instance of **FirefoxOptions** and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

  public class A_Firefox_Headless
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/path/to/geckodriver");
          FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
          options.addArguments("--headless");
          WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(options);
          System.out.println("Mozilla Firefox Headless Browser Initialized");
          driver.get("http://www.google.com");
          System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  1528817592552   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.1
  1528817592563   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:23550
  1528817593461   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "--headless" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\ATECHM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.M2jv24VJ0QMg"
  *** You are running in headless mode.
  1528817597139   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 8949
  1528817597577   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
  Jun 12, 2018 9:03:17 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
  INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
  Mozilla Firefox Headless Browser Initialized
  Page Title is : Google
  ```

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/path/to/geckodriver");
        firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.addArguments("--headless");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);

Error Remains the Same

Comment: So far the difference with our environment is OS. I am using Ubuntu (Linux), your example is with Windows. Additionally what version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: You are using _Java_, you havn't declared what is **firefoxOptions** and **driver** all about. You need to declare **firefoxOptions** as an instance of **FirefoxOptions** and **driver** as an instance of **WebDriver** as well

Comment: *firefoxOptions* was declared as FirefoxOptions outside of the code snippet. However, driver was declared as FirefoxDriver not WebDriver outside the code snippet. I made the change and still recieve the same error. 

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/path/to/geckodriver"); FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions(); firefoxOptions.addArguments("--headless"); WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);

Comment: You need to replace `"/path/to/geckodriver"` with the absolute path of the **geckodriver**